# Minimizing if statement that contains and is conditioned on an expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, variable-assignment

I often have to write lines such as:

```
if exp(var1):
   new_variable = exp2(exp(var1))
```

As you can see, this statement evaluates `exp` twice - one for the condition and then within the body of the `if` statement. Is there a neat pythonic way to write this so that `exp` is evaluated only once?

I know that I can write:

```
temp_variable = exp(var1)
if temp_variable:
     new_variable = exp2(temp_variable)
```

but this introduces a new variable. My question specifically is if there is a solution that's more **elegant** than this one.

Comment: I don't know of a way that doesn't introduce a new variable. `if temp := exp(var1): exp2(temp)` can be used to inline the assignment though.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with introducing another variable. In fact, one purpose of having variables is to store intermediate results for further reuse.

Comment: @DYZ. Not to mention that just because you didn't name a variable, doesn't mean it wasn't created.

Comment: @mkrieger1. I think I've made the answer sufficiently different to justify this not being a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand the tradeoff you are making here. As soon as you run `exp(var1)`, the return value gets made. It may be dereferenced and garbage collected immediately after the `if` check runs, but the variable does exist at that point. So both calls to `exp(var1)` create an object. What they do not do, is assign it to a name in your current namespace.

So the tradeoff is to run a (potentially expensive) computation twice, or pollute your namespace with a temporary name. In my opinion, the latter option is foolish to even consier: there are many ways that you can use an effective name.

Prior to python 3.8's [assignment expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions), introduced via [PEP-572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/), you had to add an extra line of code:

```
well_named_result = exp(var1)
if well_named_result:
   new_variable = exp2(well_named_result)
```

In python 3.8 and later, you can use the `:=` [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#assignment-expressions) to save even that minor encroachment:

```
if well_named_result := exp(var1):
   new_variable = exp2(well_named_result)
```

Now if you wanted to call `exp2` regardless, but with different parameters depending on the initial trithiness, that you could indeed to without the extra name:

```
new_variable = exp2(exp(var1) or some_default_value)
```